# transferring values throw classes on thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, object, instance

sadly for the third time i ask this question and i think every time i ask it doesn't make sense but yeah lets try once more with more words/codes also photos and simple test
i have 2 classes , one receive packets and get values from them and the other one should be using those values but i failed to get them from this class
NOTE : this values are gona be used by a new thread
so lets show the codes

```
namespace ProxyParadise.Network.Packets
{

    public class PacketHandler
    {
        public PacketHandler() // takes no parameters using get/set , failed take 1
        {
            Console.WriteLine("defining an object to get x,y take 1, value now is (" + actualX + "," + actualY + ")");
        }
        public void getxy(ushort Actualx, ushort Actualy) //using get and set with parameters failed take 2
        {
            Console.WriteLine("defining an object to get x,y take 2, value now is (" + actualX + "," + actualY + ")");
            actualX = actualX; Actualy = actualY;
        }
        public ushort actualX { get; set; }
        public ushort actualY { get; set; }
public unsafe void HandleServer(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                    var type = *((ushort*)(ptr + 2));
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case 10010:
                            {
                                if (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 24) != 0)
                                {
                                    actualX = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 24);
                                    actualY = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 26);
                                    Console.WriteLine("account coords updated to (" + actualX + "," + actualY + ")");
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
```

and here is a picture testing the this and it will writeline on the console everytime it's updated once i receive this packet
[image: test 1]
now im trying to get those values on the other class so i do some stuff with them and send packets to the server too , so here is the other class (the whole class so it make sense to who say that i should not post the important parts)

```
public class ClientBase
{
    GameUser role2;
    PacketHandler ph = new PacketHandler();
        public ushort X, Y;
        PacketHandler ph2 = new PacketHandler();

    public ClientBase(GameUser role)
    {
        role2 = role;
        Thread T = new Thread(HuntThread) { Name = "Hunt Thread" };
        T.Start(this);
        Console.WriteLine("with name : " +T.Name +  " with execution context : "+T.ExecutionContext +" with state : "+ T.IsAlive + " with id : " + T.ManagedThreadId);
       T.Join();
    }
    Monster GetNextkill()
    {
       // byte Range = 18;
        Monster CurrentTarget = null;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Monster> Pair in Dictionary.Clone(Dictionary.Monsters))
        {
          //  if (Math.Max(Math.Abs( - Pair.Value.X), Math.Abs(pp.Y - Pair.Value.Y)) > 18)
          //  {
          //      Dictionary.Monsters.Remove(Pair.Key);
          //  }
           // else if (Math.Max(Math.Abs( - Pair.Value.X), Math.Abs(pp.Y - Pair.Value.Y)) <= Range)
           // {
           //     Range = (byte)Math.Max(Math.Abs(this.X - Pair.Value.X), Math.Abs(this.Y - Pair.Value.Y));
                CurrentTarget = Pair.Value;
             //   Console.WriteLine("there is " + Dictionary.Monsters.Count + " monster around you");
          //  }
        }
        return CurrentTarget;
    }
    public void HuntThread(object Sender)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientBase Client = Sender as ClientBase;
            while (true)
            {
                Monster Target = GetNextkill();
                if (Target != null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketStructure ps = new ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketStructure();
                    //       ps.__Packet1022XP(Target.UID, Target.X, Target.Y); 
                    int xxx = Target.X - 1;
                    int yyy = Target.Y - 1;
                    ph2.getxy(X, Y);
                    Console.WriteLine("x and y in the thread is " + X + Y);
                    ps.__Packet10010(Target.X, Target.Y, role2, "normal", "server", ph.actualX, ph.actualY);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ps.__Packet10010(Target.X, Target.Y, role2, "sdasdsa", "client", role2.X, role2.Y);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ps.__Packet1022NONEXP(Target.UID, Target.X , Target.Y, role2);
                    //if fatal strike is on attack the monster 
                    //else
                    //jump next to the target and attack
                    Dictionary.Monsters.SafeRemove(Target.UID);

                }
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("expection error : " + ex);
        }
    }
    public uint UID;

}
```

so now the problem is that both ways of set/get and defining an object to get the values (i did it twice by trying to get them from method also a struct but failed at both cases)

now here is the test image 
[image]

im in doubt why it's zero , i sometimes think it's because the new object and other times i think it's because of the thread

i really wish to get help this time as i've been 4 days trying at the same thing and did so many ways that i heard of (but not the locks)
and im really thankful for you for reading this and helping me with your time and information i appreciated this :)
also thanks for the mod that will fix my spelling and grammer

Answer (score 0):

Are the uppercase/lowercase letters in the names the parameters and the properties that you've shown here the exact same as in the code you're running?

```
public void getxy(ushort Actualx, ushort Actualy) //using get and set with parameters failed take 2
{
    Console.WriteLine("defining an object to get x,y take 2, value now is (" + actualX + "," + actualY + ")");
    actualX = actualX; Actualy = actualY;
}
```

Because if I change the names of the parameters you should see why this looks wrong.

```
public void getxy(ushort inputx, ushort inputy) //using get and set with parameters failed take 2
{
    Console.WriteLine("defining an object to get x,y take 2, value now is (" + actualX + "," + actualY + ")");
    actualX = actualX; inputy = actualY;
}
```

This would certainly explain why they're always zero, they're never getting changed.

Have you tried putting in break points in the code and stepping through the code in debug, particularly the getxy method to see exactly what the input and output values are each time?

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply , this was a typo but it only affect actualx not actualy or with your words actualx not inputy , but both are zeros , so yeah after fixing this the problem still there , and yes i did try to trace it but still clueless AS i get way many threads and it keep doing step on 20 step on 20 thread then one step at main program , but even when i gone there by tracing the  some thread i find it zero but by tracing the normal code i find the right values

Comment: i did it once again , if i don't call the method/struct with an object  from thread it gives the right value but when i call it from thread it gives zero :O clueless

Comment: I would recommend that you read this for a start to help with your threading: http://www.albahari.info/threading/threading.pdf. But I think I see another problem in the code, in HuntThread you're calling ph2.getxy(X,Y), but I don't see anywhere in the code that X and Y are being set. Don't use trace, actually put in a breakpoint on that line, run the thing in Debug mode, and step through the code and inspect the values of X and Y every time that gets hit. Also you don't ever seem to be using xxx and yyy from the line about ph2.getxy